# How to handle editors who edit the post wrong

Tags: support, questions, edits, etiquette

I shared a piece of code in my question, that apparently had some characters missing that were causing the root of my problem. Telling me this would have solved my problem. However, a user chose to edit the missing characters back into my post.

Luckily someone answered the question before the edit was made, and I noticed what went wrong, but what should one do when a 'wrong' edit was made?

Do you simply reverse? Is there a way to flag this person? If they don't know they are doing anything wrong they will probably keep doing it.

Comment: On your own post you can always roll-back to a previous revision. You can @-mention an editor in a comment (it doesn't auto complete but they will get the notification) informing them why you rolled-back the edit. If this editor has an history of making such wrong edits you can flag either one of the posts they edit for a moderator and explain why those edits are wrong and should be stopped. If you are on Stack Overflow and you want to know if an edit was good or bad you can visit the SOCVR chat room. They have regulars that moderate SO Main and can help in making the right call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are reviewing, you can simply reject and move on.

In your own posts, you can always revert back to a previous edit via the drop down menu above the editing box.

You can also notify an editor in comments using @theirname, it may seem as though you can't, but they will get the notification.

If one editor does this frequently, flag an edited post for moderator attention, and explain what's happening.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid... there's a dropdown? I thought you had to rollback from the revision list

Comment: @Cai There are two options. The dropdown lets you edit from a certain revision, the revision list is just to rollback (IIRC)

Comment: Oh right yeh! The dropdown only appears if you're editing a revision though, so there's no need to go to the edit screen if all you want is a straight rollback with no edit.

Comment: @Cai true, by using the drop down you can apply an edit summary that explains the rollback, otherwise you can't.

Comment: @Cai: If memory serves, the dropdown always appears if you don't have 2k (even if you're the post author).

Comment: @NathanTuggy, it always appears for me, so I'd assume it appears for other people too

Comment: @Travis: 2kers edit using an inline AJAX form that doesn't have the revision dropdown.

Comment: @Nathan you are correct, I havn't done many <2k edits in a while or edited a specific revision so forgot it existed :)